# Posgresql - find gender count

Tags: sql, postgresql

This my dataset and i want to find No. of gender

```
name|gender|
----+------+
AA  |Male  |
BB  |Male  |
CC  |Male  |
DD  |Female|
EE  |Female|
```

sql query :

```
    select 
    gender,count(*)
from 
    schoolofit.user_request_1
group by gender
```

result:

```
gender|count|
------+-----+
Female|    2|
Male  |    3|
```

But i am looking for below result format

```
gender-1 | gender-2
-------------------
Male     | Female
3        |  2
```

Note : looking for sql query with and without using Union

Comment: It may not your answer but you can search "crosstab" function on Postgres. This function works like your question.

Comment: In your expected result format;  The Male count should be 3 and Female Count 2 based on the input data (table)

Comment: @Tushar.. typo. corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `filter` clause :

`CAST` count to varchar to be able to union the gender count with the first row (male, female).

```
select *
from (
   select 'Male' as "gender-1", 'Female' as "gender-2"
  Union
   select CAST(count(*) filter (where gender = 'Male') as varchar) as "gender-1",
   CAST(count(*) filter (where gender = 'Female') as varchar) as "gender-2"
   from user_request_1
) as s
order by "gender-1" desc
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/L0ujIq6r)

Comment: By the time I was resolving `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer:`;

You completed the answer !!
+1

Comment: Yes, datatypes in union rows must be the same

Comment: Yup ! Offcourse :)

Comment: Have any other option .. without using union and union all

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to [convert row values of your current query result to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52552461/converting-row-values-to-columns-in-result-using-case-statement)

This can be achieved using [CASE STATEMENT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) :

```
select 
    SUM(case when gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) AS "gender-1",
    SUM(case when gender = 'Female' then 1 ELSE 0 end) AS "gender-2"
from 
    user_request_1;
```

Update :
Based on the input and clarification :

```
select * from (select 'Male' AS "gender-1", 'Female' AS "gender-2"
UNION
select 
  CAST(SUM(case when gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar) AS "gender-1",
  CAST(SUM(case when gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar) AS "gender-2"
from user_request_1) as user_request
order by "gender-1" desc;
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4f131/21); where I have used data provided by you in post.

Comment: my expected output format is different. Please have a look. Gender value also one of the row

Comment: Ok,
I will add it to the query

Comment: @Tushar You're emulating a SQL:2003 [aggregate filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) available in [PostgreSQL since 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.4.0/#AEN124521): `count(*) filter (where gender = 'Male')`.

Comment: Yes @Zegarek; As SO needs a output in different format. SO has already used `count(*)`

Comment: @Zegarek; Yup; The other user has completed answer using `count(*)`  :)

Comment: @Tushar I wasn't suggesting that's *the* way to solve this but just pointing out that you're emulating something that's been long available - just letting you know you no longer need to. It's not about `count()`, it's about the `filter (where`. The `count()` could also have been used with `filter` emulation: `count(case when gender = 'Male' then 1 end)` - non-male will result in null and get discarded by the function, therefore counting only 'Male'. And vice versa, you could deploy `sum()` with a filter: `sum(1) filter (where gender = 'Male')`.

Comment: @Zegarek; Yup.  You are right and `a kind soul guiding people to write queries in lot of ways` !!
I appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

When the values can be dynamic, and not just 'Male' or 'Female' you can do:

```sql
WITH ABC as 
(  select 
     gender, 
     dense_rank() over (order by gender) r
   from user_request_1
) 
select 
  MIN(CASE WHEN r=1 THEN gender END) as "gender-1",
  MIN(CASE WHEN r=2 THEN gender END) as "gender-2"
from ABC
union all
select 
  SUM(CASE WHEN r=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::varchar as "count-1",
  SUM(CASE WHEN r=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::varchar as "count-2"
from ABC
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/bAe77got)

Answer (score 0):

One option to avoid using a union, you can use an array then unnest it as the following:

```
select unnest(mcnt) as gender_1,
       unnest(fcnt) as gender_2 
from
(
  select 
   array['Male', count(*) filter (where gender = 'Male')::text] as mcnt,
   array['Female', count(*) filter (where gender = 'Female')::text] as fcnt
  from table_name
) t
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iGud5DhZ)